# Does librdkafka c++ library have a mock server or broker?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, apache-kafka

Does librdkafka c++ library have a mock server for unit testing that doesn't require you to spin up a kafka server? If it does not, then is there a lightweight kafka server that is simple and easy to use with it?

Do the examples and unit testing in the librdkafka library require a kafka server stood up to run? If not what is it using? I see it lists localhost:9092, does it spin up its own mock broker when starting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

librdkafka does not have a mock broker, it relies on connecting to a real Apache Kafka cluster consisting of at least 3 brokers. A test.conf configuration file is passed to the tests to point out bootstrap broker addresses, et.al.

To simplify this process I wrote the [trivup](https://github.com/edenhill/trivup) tool that automatically sets up a cluster of brokers on the local machine, configured for SASL (PLAIN, SCRAM, Kerberos), SSL, or whatever environment needs to be tested. Auxiliary components such as Zookeeper or Kerberos KDC are also configured and started.

When testing is done the cluster is torn down and removed.

**Install trivup**

```
$ virtualenv ~/yourPythonVirtualEnv/bin/activate
$ source ~/yourPythonVirtualEnv/bin/activate
$ git clone https://github.com/edenhill/trivup.git
$ cd trivup
$ python setup.py install
```

**Start cluster and run shell**

```
$ cd ~/librdkafka/tests
$ ./interactive_broker_version.py 1.0.0
(trivup-shell)$ echo $BROKERS
(trivup-shell)$ make   # to run tests
...
(trivup-shell)$ exit   # stop cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as of v1.3.0, librdkafka has mocking facilities, but the api is experimental and subject to removal. From the release notes:

'Added experimental (subject to change or removal) mock broker to make application and librdkafka development testing easier'